# Textmate 2: Open files from Finder or Terminal in new tabs instead of new windows?

Tags: macos, textmate

Textmate 2 Users,

I have a nagging issue with TM2 that I can't seem to find an answer for.

I have set my 'Projects' folder to my user home directory (~). Now, if I open a file with the TM file browser it opens in a new tab (good) but files opened from the Finder or with the mate command from the Terminal always open in new windows, even if they are in my 'Projects' directory (bad).

Is there a way to force TM to open files in a new tab in an existing window regardless of how they are opened?

Thanks!